# IllegalArgumentException while initiating a call passing # character

Tags: android

I am trying to initiate a call by passing '#' character with numbers. But when i pass that uri an exception is occured as shown below

01-21 10:36:21.247: WARN/System.err(383): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in fragment at index 104:

My code is

```
      public String getHttpConnectionToServer(String uri, String proxyIP,
               Integer port, String debugMode) {

         HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(uri);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream is = entity.getContent();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}


Exception is thrown at this line of code : HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(uri);
```

How can i resolve that?? Please HElp

Comment: Can you show full URI? I mean how it looks?

Comment: 01-21 11:34:42.128: INFO/System.out(458): STRING URI : destinationNo=12333338#####

Answer (score 1):

Try http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html

I think this might be the problem.